# MVVM Light RelayCommand no works longer after Visual Studio update

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I'm developing a WPF application with MVVM Light 5.4.1.
The .NET Framework is 4.6.2.
I use RelayCommand :

```
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand TestCommand { get; set; }

    private string _test = "test";

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        TestCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(_test);
        });
    }
}
```

I have a button binded on this RelayCommand. When I click on this, nothing happens. If I print a string constant then the RelayCommand works :

```
Debug.WriteLine("test");
```

Note that this command worked before I update Visual Studio Community 2017 from version 15.4.5 to 15.7.3. I suspect a change in version of WPF. Have you ever encountered this problem ?

Comment: If I create a Test function, this works :`TestCommand = new RelayCommand(Test);

...

public void Test()
{
    Debug.WriteLine(_test);
}`

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at Debug.WriteLine and debug, does it get hit? Then you know that there is nothing wrong with the command implementation nor WPF.

Comment: The debug mode doesn't pass by the breakpoint.

Comment: But it does when you call Debug.WriteLine("test")? This makes no sense I am afraid.

Comment: Yes it does with the constant string. It's crazy.